# Is there some free space on this sda3 partition?

Tags: centos, partition

Total space of `sda3` is 80.2 GiB ( 29.8 + .218 + 3.7 + 30 + 6.3 = 70.018 )
I don't understand where is the rest 80.2 -70.018 = 10.182 GB

[image]

```
[root@centos ~]# df -hT
Filesystem              Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root xfs        30G  6.0G   24G  21% /
devtmpfs                devtmpfs  7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs                   tmpfs     7.8G   43M  7.7G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   tmpfs     7.8G   18M  7.7G   1% /run
tmpfs                   tmpfs     7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centos-home xfs        30G   21G  9.3G  70% /home
/dev/mapper/centos-var  xfs       6.3G  3.7G  2.7G  58% /var
/dev/mapper/centos-boot xfs       221M  175M   47M  80% /boot
tmpfs                   tmpfs     1.6G   32K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb5               vfat       29G  757M   29G   3% /run/media/mukesh/SANDISK
/dev/sdc1               fuseblk   2.8T  269G  2.5T  10% /run/media/mukesh/Elements
/dev/sda6               fuseblk   199G  121G   78G  62% /run/media/mukesh/Local Disk SSD
/dev/sda5               fuseblk   119G  109G   10G  92% /run/media/mukesh/Local Disk SSD1
/dev/sda2               fuseblk    70G   59G   12G  84% /run/media/mukesh/Local Disk SSD2
```

`fdisk /dev/sda` output :

```
Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5a508cde

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          208896   145287167    72539136    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       145287168   313476344    84094588+  83  Linux
/dev/sda4       313476345   976771071   331647363+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       313476408   561230774   123877183+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       561231872   976771071   207769600    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

`vgdisplay -v` output

```
    Using volume group(s) on command line.
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               centos
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  6
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                5
  Open LV               5
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               70.02 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              17926
  Alloc PE / Size       17925 / 70.02 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       1 / 4.00 MiB
  VG UUID               DLdDuG-mytg-aMZs-OaJ3-CRzG-2z4r-sp5Btf

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/centos/boot
  LV Name                boot
  VG Name                centos
  LV UUID                Q2XDnm-UxsM-XY0q-BbR1-6tOD-zLKu-1Jduhk
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost, 2016-03-03 22:26:22 +0530
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                224.00 MiB
  Current LE             56
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/centos/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                centos
  LV UUID                R4x09z-Mt0a-T9TW-VIEj-bfNX-Lf5G-lpJYhP
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost, 2016-03-03 22:26:22 +0530
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                29.80 GiB
  Current LE             7628
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/centos/home
  LV Name                home
  VG Name                centos
  LV UUID                9mkF24-VeHW-luVs-UF62-yQTG-3Lj0-6tgx6m
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost, 2016-03-03 22:26:23 +0530
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                30.00 GiB
  Current LE             7679
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:3

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/centos/var
  LV Name                var
  VG Name                centos
  LV UUID                pmsJiw-HqoT-dqyi-XaEc-JT8v-bU07-hf16Xn
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost, 2016-03-03 22:26:23 +0530
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                6.28 GiB
  Current LE             1608
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:4

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/centos/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                centos
  LV UUID                rdlDnE-t62f-LMAo-l4ao-GkDq-6Iy9-sJ7BIm
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost, 2016-03-03 22:26:23 +0530
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                3.73 GiB
  Current LE             954
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:2

  --- Physical volumes ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda3     
  PV UUID               Iw7LYC-j6Bz-P1Lw-uqCz-kc0W-dElK-rqsQoI
  PV Status             allocatable
  Total PE / Free PE    17926 / 1
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to have Volume group of 70 gb out of 80 gb /dev/sda3.

Comment: count is right, volume group centos only have 70.02 Gb, it seems strange sda2 count as 70 Gb, with less block, partition sda3 look like 80Gb, may be volume group formatting prevent whole disk to be use (bad combination of PE size and max PE extend), but I doubt it.

Comment: just now i installed gparted  and it says that `10.18 GiB of unallocated space within the partition.
To grow the file system to fill the partition, select the partition and choose the menu item:
Partition --> Check.` let me add that too in the question ...its becoming really long

Comment: Gparted seems to show unallocated space, which i cannot see from command line.I want to add some space to`/home` and `/boot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PV is 17926 physical extents large (with 4MiB PEs, that's 70.02 GiB), which means it doesn't take the full extent of the partition.

Possibly the partition was enlarged after the PV was created. You should be able to use `pvresize` to let it stretch to the full extent of the partition.

BTW, `vgs`, `lvs` and `pvs` are good commands to quickly show allocation in VG/LV/PVs.

See also `pvs --units B -o all | less -S` for precise and complete information about PVs.

Comment: you were right `partition was enlarged after the PV was created` pvresize worked to stretch to the full extent of the partion.Now my job is to add some space to /boot and /home

Comment: OK, i was able to resize lv /dev/mapper/centos-home using `lvresize --size +5000M /dev/mapper/centos-home` and filesystem using `xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/centos-home`